# Ajax does not actualize listview in wicket

Tags: java, ajax, listview, wicket

I would like to create wicket page where is displayed table with data from database, under this table, there is form which create another objects into database. When I save object, page does not refresh, so in table I cannot see new row.
If I understood it correctly, to solve this issue I have to use ajax. I found guide (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+repaint+a+ListView+via+Ajax) and created something similar in my project, but it does not work and I can not find the reason why does it not work. I found that another people had problems that they tried to actualize just only rows/panel, but it is not my case. I do not get even any exception, just it does nothing. Could you please give me an advice?

.java file

```
public class ListPanel extends Panel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6953172817971228490L;

    @SpringBean
    RezervaceDao rezervaceDao;

    public ListPanel(String id) {
        super(id);

        List<Rezervace> rezervace = rezervaceDao.getAllRezervace();
        ListView listview = new ListView("rezervaceList", rezervace) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 3659733406689720345L;

            protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
                Rezervace r = (Rezervace) item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("casRezervace", r.getCasRezervace()));
                item.add(new Label("jmeno", r.getJmeno()));
                item.add(new Label("adresa", r.getAdresa()));
                item.add(new Label("telefon", r.getTelefon()));
            }
        };
        listview.setReuseItems(true);

        // encapsulate the ListView in a WebMarkupContainer in order for it to
        // update
        WebMarkupContainer listContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("obal");
        // generate a markup-id so the contents can be updated through an AJAX
        // call
        listContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        listContainer
                .add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(3)));
        // add the list view to the container
        listContainer.add(listview);
        // finally add the container to the page
        add(listContainer);

    }
}
```

.html file

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="obal">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Čas návštěvy</th>
                <th>Jméno a Příjmení</th>
                <th>Adresa</th>
                <th>Kontaktní telefon</th>
            </tr>
            <tr wicket:id="rezervaceList">
                <td><span wicket:id="casRezervace"></span></td>
                <td><span wicket:id="jmeno"></span></td>
                <td><span wicket:id="adresa"></span></td>
                <td><span wicket:id="telefon"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
List<Rezervace> rezervace = rezervaceDao.getAllRezervace();
ListView listview = new ListView("rezervaceList", rezervace)
```

The list view initializes itself with a static list. It should instead ask the DB for new data on every refresh.

Read https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models#WorkingwithWicketmodels-DynamicModels about static vs. dynamic models.

Comment: Yes, this will work. Small note: I would call the list is 'fixed' (as 'static' might cause confusion with `static`)